# Facebook marketing API XML format

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

i have one of demo xml file from Facebook:
https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpt1/t39.2178-6/12809155_972144936209928_1434038580_n.xml

Copy this code to Facebook debugger (https://business.facebook.com/ads/product_feed/debug/)
and get error: "Please check that your file is in the correct format. Supported file formats include CSV, TSV or RSS/ATOM XML. (0 products affected)"

What is wrong? Why this format is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It can be fixed by removing the leading whitespace characters so that the first line starts with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```